# Wich better to write some algorithm in Model or Controller Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a project using some algorithm. I write the code in Model and it was done. However most code that I saw in here or in some website is written in Controller. Is it good idea to write the algorithm in Model? My code is disorganized. Could you give me suggestion? Am I need to recode in Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC pattern is a flexible pattern and there's not "the one way" to implement it. In general the model should provide small functions without much logic like getters/setters. Here you could for example also include methods for saving to the database (CI does it like this in their documentation). More complex logic should be done in the controller. Although this is not a fixed rule it is better practice than having a complex algorithm in the model because it's easier to maintain/extend the code. You also stated that your code is disorganized so I think you almost gave yourself the answer to the question "Am I need to recode in Controller?". You should but you don't have to if you just want it to work.

Hope this helps but I think this is also kind of an opinionated question

Comment: Yes, maybe it's best way because I can easily debugging the program without parse to Controller. But some day I will clean up my code. Thanks for your opinion.